# How can I stop the interval?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making a `setInterval` method in my discord bot, but I have an issue in stopping the Interval.
Look at my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();


client.once('ready', () => {

  console.log('Im online');

});


client.on('message', async msg => {

var interval;

if(msg.content == '!spam')
{
interval = setInterval(() => {
    msg.channel.send('test');
   }, 2000);
}

if(msg.content.startsWith('!stop'))
{
clearInterval(interval);
}

});
```

That should definitely work, right?
If you know the answer please help me!!

Comment: Can you post the full code of this file, including any containing functions?

Comment: Oh you want me to post a 1000 lines of code file

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's too much. Can you at least include the ancestor blocks to the code in the question? It's a scope issue, should be pretty easy to tweak with some context

Comment: Ok I will do it

Comment: This fails if someone writes "!spam" twice in a row, as you will forget the first interval (it's being overwritten).

Comment: I'm just trying to test it and then add some other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
client.on('message', async msg => {
   var interval;
```

This creates a new variable binding `interval` *every single time* the message handler runs. Inside any single message handler, either

```
  interval = setInterval(() => {
     msg.channel.send('test');
  }, 2000);
```

will run, or

```
  if (msg.content.startsWith('!stop')) {
     clearInterval(interval);
  }
```

will run (or neither will run). But the `interval` is not persistent outside of the function, so further messages will be attempting to clear a different interval binding.

Make `interval` persistent instead, and also check that you don't start an interval while one is already going on:

```
let interval;
client.on('message', (msg) => {
   if (msg.content == '!spam' && !interval) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
         msg.channel.send('test');
      }, 2000);
   }
   if (msg.content.startsWith('!stop')) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = null;
   }
});
```